# Как перезагрузить смартфон на Android из консоли?

Tags: android

Сломалась кнопка вызова меню ребута/выключения.

Поставил консоль Android terminal emulator, ввожу reboot, пишет permission denied.

Возможно, нужно залогиниться рутом, но команду su - не понимает, sudo тоже.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы перезагрузиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте зажать одновременно кнопку домой и уменьшение звука. Держите подольше. Должно выскачить меню как от кнопки блокировки (вроде как симметричные команды)

Comment: Внизу три кнопки - средняя, получается домой? Жму ее и уменьшение звука, не получается.

Comment: нужно зажать (полагаю секунд на 7). И Какой у вас android?

Comment: Android  5, зажимал на более, чем 10 сек

Comment: попробуйте с мобильного приложения https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antaresone.quickreboot&hl=ru Только вот мне интересно, как вы его потом включите бе кнопки?

Comment: Добавил скрин, что зажимал

Comment: У меня виртуальные кнопки, поэтому я зажимаю нижнюю громкости и кнопку блокировки. Попробуйте вы так же.

Comment: Android terminal emulator permission

https://jdrch.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/how-to-start-android-terminal-emulator-as-root/